# Application's html loads, but js function built with angular gets stuck loading indefinitely

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cookies

I'm working on an AngularJS application that reads and writes cookies and my javascript code is not working properly. My html loads fine, but when it comes to load the angular script it gets stuck loading indefinitely.

I've tried with a simple 'hello world' console log with a simple angular function and it works fine, which means the problem is not located on the angular script, but on the cookie function itself, although I can't point out where and since the page's not loading at all, I can't see any output on the console.

Here's my html code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app = 'cookieApp'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller = 'MainController'>
            <label>Save cookie:</label>
            <input ng-model = 'value'>
            <button ng-click = 'saveCookie(value);'>Save</button>
            <h2>Get Cookie : {{getCookie()}}</h2>
            <script src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js'></script>
            <script src = 'app.js'></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the javascript code

```
angular.module('cookieApp', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'cookie', function($scope, cookie){
    $scope.value = '';
    $scope.saveCookie = function(value){
        cookie.write('cap_value', value);
    }
    $scope.getCookie = function(){
        return cookie.read('cap_value');
    }
}]).
factory('cookie', [function(){
    return{
        read: function(name){
            var i, c, nameEQ = name + '=';
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(i = 0; i < ca.length; i++){
                c = ca[i];
                while(c.charAt(0) == ''){
                    c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                }
                if(c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0){
                    return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return '';
        },
        write: function(name, value){
            date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (72*4));
            expires = '; expires = ' + date.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path = /';
        }
    }
}]);
```

I expect the application to save a cookie when I type an input and then print it in the `<h2>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're aware of the [`ngCookies` module](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.32/docs/api/ngCookies), but it's basically the answer to your problem. It provides the `$cookies` service, which is the "proper" way to work with cookies, within an AngularJS application. I've combined your HTML and JavaScript into this snippet, which works exactly as I think you're expecting:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='cookieApp'>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>AngularJS Cookie Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller='MainController'>
  <label>Save cookie:</label>
  <input ng-model='value'>
  <button ng-click='saveCookie(value);'>Save</button>
  <h2>Get Cookie : {{getCookie()}}</h2>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js'></script>
  <!-- including the ngCookies module here -->
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular-cookies.js'></script>
  <script>
    // adding `ngCookies` to the dependencies
    angular.module('cookieApp', ['ngCookies']).controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$cookies', function ($scope, $cookies) {
      $scope.value = '';
      $scope.saveCookie = function (value) {
        $cookies.cap_value = value;
      };

      $scope.getCookie = function () {
        return $cookies.cap_value;
      };
    }]);
  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'll point out that [the API changed in version 1.4](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies), they added getters and setters. Just be aware of that, if you decide to upgrade your AngularJS version at some point in the future.